# How to tell if a String is naturally sorted alphabetically or not - java

Tags: java, string, methods, alphabetical

I am using Java to create a method called **isOrdered** to tell if a string is sorted naturally in alphabetical order. For example, if the input was "effort" or "Aaaabbyy" the method would return **true**, compared to "hello" that would return **false** since the letter 'h' appears after the letter 'e'.

I have worked out this so far,

```
public class orderWording {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(isOrdered("effort")); //should appear true
    }
    public static boolean isOrdered (String s) {
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == /*alphabet */ ) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
       }
    }
}
```

However, I don't know how to match each character with the alphabet to know if the string is naturally in alphabetical order.

I thought about making a nested loop within the **isOrdered** method. While the first loop is traversing the string, the second loop is matching those characters with the order of the alphabet.

Something similar to this,

```
    public static boolean isOrdered (String s) {
       String a = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < a.length(); j ++){
               if (s.charAt(i) == a.charAt(j) ) {
                   return true;
               }
               else {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Although, I am not sure if this is a correct way to solve this problem.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should solve your issue. I added another method to check if it sorted in descending fashion as well.

```
public class OrderWording {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(isAscendingOrdered("effort")); //true
       System.out.println(isAscendingOrdered("java")); //false
       System.out.println(isDescendingOrdered("Yea")); //true
    }

    public static boolean isAscendingOrdered (String s) {
       s=s.toUpperCase();
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i ++) {
          if (s.charAt(i)>s.charAt(i+1))
              return false;                
       }
       return true;
    }

    public static boolean isDescendingOrdered (String s) {
       s=s.toUpperCase();
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i ++) {
          if (s.charAt(i)<s.charAt(i+1))
              return false;       
       }
       return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Nice work. I think you could enhance your answer if you explain a few more of your decisions, like why you make the string upper case, or why you only iterate `n-1` letters

Comment: Thanks. Sure. 1. I made it upper case was to have an uniform case for all the letters in the word. The code would work the same if toLowerCase() is used instead of toUpperCase(). 2. Iteration only till n-1 because the condition checks i+1th character. Iteration till n would result in ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. 3.The condition in if depends if it's supposed to be ascending or descending. It checks the ASCII value of characters in the string. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class orderWording {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(isOrdered("effort")); //should appear true
    }
    public static boolean isOrdered (String s) {
   boolean issorted=true;
       for (int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i ++) {
            if (Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i)) >Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i+1) ) {
                issorted=false;
                break;
            }
       } return issorted;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to have a flag here. You can simply return false if you find a violation (char at index *i* > char at index *i + 1*). Also, your terminating condition must be `i < s.length() - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of sort method from Java. Create a simple method to sort String:

```
public static String sortString(String str) 
{ 
    // convert string to char array 
    char chrArray[] = str.toCharArray(); 

    // sort string in array
    Arrays.sort(chrArray); 

    // return sorted string 
    return new String(chrArray); 
}
```

To check if your String is sorted:

```
String str1 = "effort";
str1.equlsIgnoreCase(sortString(str1));  //true

String str2 = "apples";
str2.equlsIgnoreCase(sortString(str2));  //false
```